# tt_news: List of categors with link

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I have a LIST VIEW in tt_news. I want to display a list of all the categories each entry belongs to, like this:

"TITLE OF NEWS
[Sports](http://#), [Travel](http://#), [Photos](http://#)"

so that each category name links to the view of all news from that category, like the CATMENU.

How could I do it? Im using genericmarkers for tt_news to add custom objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the extraItemMarkerProcessor we [were talking about before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10193471/1066240) and insert new marker ie. `###ITEM_CATEGORIES###`. Then you can use some kind of loop for every category to build link with and pass it to the marker as a list of coma-separated links:

```
$pObj->cObj->typolink($catName, $catLinkConfArray);
```

Building links with typolink is [documented in TSref](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.6.0/view/1/5/#id1794502)